# Show images from folder php (horizontal)

Tags: css

I have this code to show my images from a folder, but the problem is that it shows the images vertically (there are 9000 images) so the scrolling is ending.

I would like to know if it's possible to make the images horizontally?

The code I use:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<title>Show images in folder</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    padding: 0;
    background: #acacac;
    text-align: center;
}
td {
    padding: 0 0 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font: 9px sans-serif;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
}
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto 10px;
    max-width: 900px;
    outline: none;
}
img:active {
    max-width: 100%;
}
a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<?php
$folder = 'album1584/';
$filetype = '*.*';
$files = glob($folder.$filetype);
$count = count($files);

$sortedArray = array();

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $sortedArray[date ('YmdHis', filemtime($files[$i]))] = $files[$i];
}

krsort($sortedArray);

echo '<table>';
foreach ($sortedArray as &$filename) {
    #echo '<br>' . $filename;
    echo '<tr><td>';
    echo '<a name="'.$filename.'" href="#'.$filename.'"><img src="'.$filename.'" /></a>';
    echo substr($filename,strlen($folder),strpos($filename, '.')-strlen($folder));
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you really want to show 9000 images on a page?

Comment: Do not use table. You insert table row for each image.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `display: block;` to `display: inline-block;` by styles for img tag.

**EDIT:**

Ok i think I know where the problem may be. You put each image in a separate table row so try to put more in one row or do not use table for that but simple container with the css change I gave you.

Comment: That made the text horizontally but not the image.

(by the way thanks for taking your time to answer)

Answer (score 0):

Images are listed vertically because they are contained in individual rows of the table. Also, in your CSS you set them to display as a block.

Remove `display: block` for images and don't put them in a table.

Also, don't display 9000 images at once. Use pagination.